# Why does kotlin have componentN functions in data class, if they already have getters and setters?

Tags: kotlin

There is a data class in kotlin, e.g.

```
@Entity
data class Record(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "name")
    var name: String? = null
)
```

And I can call component1 and component2 functions to access the properties. However, as I declare the property var, I have getter and setter, and if I declare property val I have the getter. Are componentN functions are redundant in this case, and why do we need them, because getters seem to be much more self-explanatory?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Kotlin supports the following syntax via `componentN` functions:

```
val (name, age) = person
```

This syntax is called a [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html). A destructuring declaration creates multiple variables at once. We have declared two new variables: name and age.

A destructuring declaration is compiled down to the following code:

```
val name = person.component1()
val age = person.component2()
```

> the component1() and component2() functions are another example of the
>   principle of conventions widely used in Kotlin (see operators like +
>   and *, for-loops etc.). Anything can be on the right-hand side of a
>   destructuring declaration, as long as the required number of component
>   functions can be called on it. And, of course, there can be
>   component3() and component4() and so on.
>
> Note that the componentN() functions need to be marked with the
>   operator keyword to allow using them in a destructuring declaration.

Comment: So, yeah, destructuring is cool. But the question is still exists. Why kotlin compiler generates `componentN` methods instead of just using getters? If you check out decompiled kotlin bytecode you'll notice that `componentN` methods and getters are exactly the same.

Comment: because it is generic rule how to destruct any not data class instance