# How to delete these components in the packaged framework

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

these components are useless, how to delete it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXllo.png

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please replace your image with real code and add kotlin code from which this code was generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attributes are generated by the Kotlin compiler, here is the reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/43158972/4487858